# How to Attach Network Directory to Docker Container - Windows 7 Host

Tags: docker

I'm testing Docker running on my Windows 7 PC. I can mount directories  under C:\Users to containers without issue with e.g.

```
docker run --rm -it -v //c/Users/someuser/:/data/ alpine ash
```

but when I try to attach a networked location like //server1/data with e.g.

```
docker run --rm -it -v //server1/data/:/data/ alpine ash
```

the /data directory in the container appears empty. How do I pass a directory *not* under C:\Users\ to my Docker containers?

Answer (score 0):

Because my PC was running Windows 7 I'd installed Docker Toolbox, which uses Virtualbox instead of Hyper-V. My understanding is that this means Docker is running inside a VM on my system, so that VM needs to have access to any data I intend to pass to Docker.

To attach network directories (or anything local above C:\Users) I needed to add it as a shared folder in Virtualbox.

VM (*default* in my case) => Settings => Shared Folders => +

After navigating the file explorer and adding //server1/data to the list of folders shared with VM 'default' I was able to pass it to the container as a volume using the second command outline in my original question.